# Crear un metodo personalizado y una ruta personalizada en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy intentando crear un metodo personalizado en mi controlador 'autorizaciones' que se llame 'mis_autorizaciones' donde ejecuto una query.
La idea es que al hacer click en una seccion de mi menu me lleve a las 'autorizaciones' que tiene realizadas el usuario logueado pero que no se muestre en el mismo html que el index por mas que sea similar la vista, sino que me redirija a un html nuevo llamado 'mis_autorizaciones.html.erb'
En mi archivo routes defini lo siguiente:

```
get '/authorisations/my_authorisations', to: 'authorisations#my_authorisations'
```

Mi controlador de autorizaciones tiene el siguiente metodo:

```
def my_authorisations
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @authorisations = Authorisation.where('affiliate_id = ?', current_user.affiliate.id_persona) }
    format.json { render json: get_data }
  end
end
```

Y cree en view/authorizations un archivo nuevo llamado 'my_authorizations.html.erb' con la tabla html donde voy a volcar mis datos. 
Si ejecuto un 'rails routes' obtengo lo siguiente:

```
authorisations_my_authorisations GET    /authorisations/my_authorisations(.:format)                                              authorisations#my_authorisations
```

Y mi boton del menu por el cual quiero acceder a 'mis autorizaciones' tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Mis Autorizaciones', authorisations_my_authorisations_path %></li>
```

Error que me tira log de la consola:

```
Started GET "/authorisations/my_autho" for ::1 at 2020-06-04 08:15:01 -0300
Processing by AuthorisationsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"my_autho"}
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 
$1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /Users/ffernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Authorisation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "authorisations".* FROM 
"authorisations" WHERE "authorisations"."user_id" = $1 AND 
"authorisations"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 3], ["id", 0], 
["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/authorisations_controller.rb:143
Rendering public/404.html within layouts/application
Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Affiliate Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "affiliates".* FROM "affiliates" WHERE 
"affiliates"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/views/layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb:80
Rendered layouts/_links_rol_affiliate.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_links_rol_secretary.html.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (16.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (22.1ms)
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00007fdd52eea1b0>  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Filter chain halted as :set_authorisation rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 245ms (Views: 235.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Comment: No entendí cuál es el problema con lo que tienes implementado actualmente. Mas bien, ¿que es lo que no te está funcionando?

Comment: Necesito que al hacer click en el boton me abra el archivo html 'my_authorizations.html.erb' que yo cree y no el index. Pero no se si esta bien lo que intente hacer que es lo que explique en la pregunta.

Comment: Pero es que insisto, ¿no te funciona al hacer click al botón? porque si lo hace, está bien, yo no veo algún problema aparente en lo que implementaste.

Comment: Exacto, no funciona. La url que yo tengo es la siguiente: authorisations_my_authorisations_path y es la que me tira 'rails routes' por ende la que puse en mi 'link_to'

Comment: Si no te funciona, ¿puedes por favor agregar a la pregunta algún error que te está arrojando? No se, en la consola rails o en la javascript ¿logra hacer el request al hacer el click por último? más info del problema

Comment: Ahi agregue a la pregunta el error que me arroja en la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en el orden de tus rutas:

```
get '/authorisations/my_authorisations', to: 'authorisations#my_authorisations'
```

debería ir antes de donde tengas definido `resource :authorisations` para que prevalezca por sobre `get '/authorisations/:id` que te dirige a `#show`.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso lo que me seco la cabeza jaja. Te agradezco mucho !